# What is best practice for managing user settings table with postgresql using sqlalchemy with fastapi

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, entity-relationship

I am trying to manage user settings by creating a table `user_settings` which references `users` table with below relationship

using [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) with [databases](https://pypi.org/project/databases/) and [sqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/) to manage database data

> table `users`

- id(primary key)
- email
- password
- status

> table `user_settings`

- id(primary key)
- email
- phone_number
- timezone
- user_id(foreign key) => users(id)

Here is how am inserting data when user registers

```
def create_user(user: UserCreate):
    query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (nextval('users_id_seq'), :email, :password, :status)"
    return database.execute(query, values={"email": user.email, "password": user.password, "status": "active"})
```

issue here is when a user signs up, i am able to populate the `users` table with a single row of the user with the email address.

How do i ensure `atomic` insert or creation of a single row in the `user_settings` table also? because this table will be used to manage the settings for the user, so it needs to link to the `users` table and always have same value of the `email` column from the `users` table

So if the email address from the `users` table is updated, the email address from the `user_settings` MUST reflect the change in the same `atomic` transaction

All help will be appreciate

Comment: You might want multiple emails and multiple phone numbers, but why would they be tied together like that?  Does a particular email own a particular phone number?  And why have email in both tables?

Comment: user settings...email will be same email to login, thus why the same email with the users table...users can then add or modify other settings like phone number, timezone etc

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the `email` field in both tables. SQL Databases should avoid data duplication wherever possible. The `email` can always be accessed by getting a reference from the other table.

Unless you plan on adding more fields for settings, this basic information seems like it would be best placed in the `users` table and there may be no need for a separate settings table.

Below I've detailed how I would lay out the two tables, assuming you will have more fields.

#### users

- id (Primary Key)
- email
- password
- status

#### user_settings

- id (Primary Key)
- user_id (Foreign Key)
- phone_number
- timezone
- ..etc..

For more information regarding relationships in sqlalchemy, I would suggest reading the SQLAlchemy documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one)

Comment: yes i plan on adding more fields under `user_settings` table...how will the table look if i were to use reference and what will change in my SQL query?

Comment: I've updated my answer, your layout is pretty much correct, it's just setting it up in SQLAlchemy you need to do. The docs are fairly straightforward

Comment: where is reference of `email` in `user_settings`?

Comment: You would insert as you would any other table. When you need to insert the user_id you simply insert the integer value of the id from the users entry. Does that make sense?

Comment: so lets say i want to run a query on `user_settings` table that returns email, phone_number, timezone how will that work?

Comment: Here the best thing to do is to read through the link I gave in the answer, it should answer all your questions

Comment: i asked a specific question that is bounded well enough...i mean you want to help or want to send me to ready up on stuffs? i gave query i used to insert rows...how will i pull email from `user_settings` table? can you add sql query in your answer?