# FastAPI Authentication with Login/Group Roles of an existing Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, authentication, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlmodel

I've read a lot of the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/), [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68980714/what-is-best-practice-for-managing-user-settings-table-with-postgresql-using-sql) and [other blogs](https://www.fastapitutorial.com/blog/database-connection-fastapi/) and none of them seems to talk about using the Login/Group Roles section (`SELECT * FROM pg_role`) of an existing Postgres Database for authentication purpose.

I'm not sure if it's a that bad practice because I'm not used with backend development but it's for internal purpose so there is not that much security needs. The main goal here is to allow the existing users to use their existing password. I would absolutely like to avoid having to maintain the Login/Group Roles section and a user table in parallel.

Anyway, I can't figure out how to implement this operation so I'll be interested if you have any clues.
Feel free to ask me to edit my question to show my current code (I wanted to keep it focus on the simple question of Login/Group Roles authentication). I have already implemented a basic CRUD connected to an existing DB as well as an authentication system with hash and JWT based on a mocked DB.

Actually, I'm mainly stuck because of the unreadable rolpassword column. When I'm using my basic [veryify_password function](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/490c554e23343eec0736b06e59b2108fdd057fdc/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/core/security.py#L29), I get this error : `{UnknownHashError}UnknownHashError('hash could not be identified', None)`.